# Using simultaneously 2 USB digital scales for monitoring

Tags: python, usb, scale, hid, digital

I have a technical issue with digital scales. Let me introduce the context of my work :

I want to use 3 digital scales simultaneously to monitor a flume experiment (scaled model of a river) sedimentary and water outputs.

Now I am new to Python (and coding to be honest), so this is my first script.
I work on the labs computer which use Windows 7, under Python 2.7.
I have downloaded and installed PyUSb and libusb.

I'll walk you through my issue as I have seen similar problems but no solution I saw online worked for me.

I use DYMO 10 kg scales.

Here is the first code I used, adapted from this link : http://steventsnyder.com/reading-a-dymo-usb-scale-using-python/

```
    import usb.core
    import usb.util
    import time

    root = "C:\\Users\\lszewczyk\\Travail\\Laboratoire\\Balance\\"

    VENDOR_ID1 = 0x0922
    PRODUCT_ID1 = 0x8003

def scale1():

    device = usb.core.find(idVendor=VENDOR_ID1, idProduct=PRODUCT_ID1)
    print VENDOR_ID1
    print PRODUCT_ID1
    # use the first/default configuration
    device.set_configuration()

    # first endpoint
    endpoint = device[0][(0,0)][0]


    fout1=open(root+'Scale1.txt', 'w')

    # read a data packet
    data1 = None
    while True:
        try:
            starttime=time.time()
            while True:
                data1 = device.read(endpoint.bEndpointAddress,
                               endpoint.wMaxPacketSize)
                grams1 = data1[4]+(256*data1[5])
                print grams1
                elapsed_time1 = time.time() - starttime
                print elapsed_time1
                fout1.write(str(grams1)+';'+str(elapsed_time1)+'\n')
                time.sleep(1 - ((time.time() - starttime) % 1)) 



        except usb.core.USBError as e:
            data1 = None
            if e.args == ('Operation timed out',):

                continue

    fout1.close()

scale1()
```

Which gives me a nice monitoring, every X seconds the weight in grams. I was very happy.
BUT, I can only use one scale that way, because of linear reading of the code and stuff.

It was when I was introduced to threads.

So I wrote this snippet of code, which does the same thing as the first, but rady for threading, and has the benefit of an end condition for the thread (otherwise I can't get my data in the output file) related to the weight registered on my scales.

```
import usb
import usb.core
import usb.util
import time
from threading import Thread


root = "C:\\Users\\lszewczyk\\Travail\\Laboratoire\\Balance\\"

class Run(Thread):
""" Thread to run the simulation then to compute outputs """
def __init__(self, idVendor, idProduct, fout):
    self.idVendor = idVendor
    self.idProduct = idProduct
    Thread.__init__(self)
    self.fout = fout
    self.max=5000

def run(self):

    device=usb.core.find()
    endpoint=device[0][(0,0)][0]
    device.set_configuration()



    output=open(self.fout, 'w')


    data = None
    starttime=time.time()
    while True:
        data = device.read(endpoint.bEndpointAddress,endpoint.wMaxPacketSize)
        grams = data[4]+(256*data[5])

        if grams<self.max:


            print grams
            elapsed_time = time.time() - starttime
            print elapsed_time
            output.write(str(grams)+';'+str(elapsed_time)+'\n')
            time.sleep(1 - ((time.time() - starttime) % 1))


        else:
            break

            output.close()

        continue
```

I then tried a thread (on at first, with only one scale) and it worked just fine, both the monitoring and the end condition. here is the output in case you are interested :

```
runfile('C:/Users/lszewczyk/Travail/Laboratoire/Balance/Thread.py', wdir='C:/Users/lszewczyk/Travail/Laboratoire/Balance')
Reloaded modules: Run
78
0.00799989700317
78
1.00300002098
78
2.00199985504
78
3.00199985504
78
4.00199985504
78
5.00199985504
78
6.00199985504
78
7.00300002098
78
8.00199985504
78
9.00199985504
78
10.001999855
78
11.003000021
78
12.003000021
```

But when I try a thread with two scales, it doesn't work. I precise that both scales work just fine independently.

Here is my script :

```
import usb.core
import usb.util
from Run import Run


root = "C:\\Users\\lszewczyk\\Travail\\Laboratoire\\Balance\\"

idVendor1=0x0922 
idProduct1=0x8006
idVendor2=0x0922 
idProduct2=0x8003

device1 = usb.core.find(idVendor=idVendor1, idProduct=idProduct1)
device2 = usb.core.find(idVendor=idVendor2, idProduct=idProduct2)

endpoint1 = device1[0][(0,0)][0]
endpoint2 = device2[0][(0,0)][0]


thread_1=(Run(idVendor1, idProduct1, root+'Scale1.txt'))
thread_2=(Run(idVendor2, idProduct2, root+'Scale2.txt'))

thread_1.start()
thread_2.start()

thread_1.join()
thread_2.join()
```

And here is the output :

```
80
0.00999999046326
Exception in thread Thread-24:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lszewczyk\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\lib\threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "Run.py", line 34, in run
    data = device.read(endpoint.bEndpointAddress,endpoint.wMaxPacketSize)
  File "C:\Users\lszewczyk\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\usb\core.py", line 905, in read
    intf, ep = self._ctx.setup_request(self, endpoint)
  File "C:\Users\lszewczyk\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\usb\core.py", line 190, in setup_request
    self.managed_claim_interface(device, intf)
  File "C:\Users\lszewczyk\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\usb\core.py", line 146, in managed_claim_interface
    self.backend.claim_interface(self.handle, i)
  File "C:\Users\lszewczyk\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\usb\backend\libusb0.py", line 468, in claim_interface
    _check(_lib.usb_claim_interface(dev_handle, intf))
  File "C:\Users\lszewczyk\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\usb\backend\libusb0.py", line 380, in _check
    raise USBError(errmsg, ret)
USBError: [Errno None] libusb0-dll:err [claim_interface] could not claim interface 0, win error: La ressource demand�e est en cours d�utilisation.


80
1.00499987602
80
2.00600004196
80
3.00600004196
80
4.00600004196
80
5.00600004196
80
6.00499987602
140
7.00600004196
```

[EDIT] I forgot the error is partly written in French, so here is the translation for the last line : 
'La ressource demand�e est en cours d�utilisation.' means 'The ressource asked for is busy'

Where one scales works fine but the other can not claim the interface 0.
I have tried all I could think of to correct the line 34 of my `Run` script. I also have tried different drivers, and many proposed solution found online to similar issues. I notably tried to target a specific interface or bus, but failed and/or nothin new came out of it.

Does anyone have a lead?
I want to precise a few things : first the core of my code is borrowed online and adapted, so it may not be the most optimized code possible. As it is my first program please be indulgent but any advice is welcome. Second I am very inexperienced so the issue might have a very simple solution, once again please be patient with me.
I remain at your disposal for any precision you might need.

Thank you in advance for any input you might have.

Yours truly,
Léo Szewczyk

Comment: Can you tell me more about the scales? Do they have on-board memory?

Comment: Hello, They do not have any on-board memory, hence the output file. they are simple digital postal scale like that : http://www.dymo.com/en-US/m10lb-digital-postal-scale

Comment: Can you tell me what endpoint = device[0][(0,0)][0] does?

Comment: The first subscript [0] accesses the first configuration of the device.
The second subscript [0,0] selects the first interface and the first alternate setting.
The third subscript [0] selects the first endpoint.
So basically it determines how the device is acceded. I tried using an alternate configuration or interface or setting, but to no avail., as the scale seems to be too simple to have them.

Comment: I believe the problem is that the libusb0-dll is attempting to claim an interface that is already being used. Humor me and try: endpoint2 = device2[1][(0,0)][0]

Comment: Thank for your input, unfortunately it returns the error 
IndexError: Invalid configuration index 1

Comment: That does seem odd. Keep on trying different configurations. Maybe try device2[1][(1,1)][1] it is definitely mad because about your configuration for the second device.

Comment: I have tried any combinaison by now. I think the device is too rudimentary to have alternate configurations or be able to connect to other interfaces. I will explore other solutions though.